# How to validate all the properties in a class in one line

Tags: c#

Assume that I have all these properties inside my `UserModel` class

```
public class UserModel
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string MiddleName { get; set; }
     public string Lastname { get; set; }
     public string Username { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And also, this method inside `UserModel` class

```
public class UserModel
{
    public void InformationValidation()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName) 
        && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleName) 
        && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Lastname) ..And the other properties)
    {
        //Validation
    }
 }
```

So how to call all the properties and store it maybe in a list or something so the `InformationValidation()` method looks much more cleaner than calling all the properties and checking it one by one?

Comment: You don't... Without some ugly, overkill reflection

Comment: You can attach the `DataAnnotation` over properties and in your method can invoke the `Validator.TryValidateObject`. With this you can apply any validation rule over declaration of property.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 See overkill below

Comment: Btw you are testing whether **all** of your properties are null/empty. Is that really what you want as opposed to **any** are empty *or* **all** are non-empty

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to do this, but it might be overkill:

```cs
static Func<UserModel, string>[] _propGetters =
    typeof(UserModel)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .Select(p => (Func<UserModel, string>)
            p.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<UserModel, string>))
        ).ToArray();


public void InformationValidation()
{
    if(_propGetters.Select(g => g(this)).All(val => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val)))
    {
        //Validation
    }
}
```

You may need to handle exactly which properties you want here. I also question your exact validation logic, but I'll leave that to you.

For multiple property types using generics, it gets much more complicated.

Comment: I'll do you one better! On mobile so it may take a sec!

Comment: Bleh you know what. I typed out a compiled  Expression solution but then I realized I don't want to promote such solutions. OP should stick with manual or DataAnnotations

Comment: I've never been a fan of Expressions, especially when it can be done otherwise. Eg. I once wrote a whole generic implementation of this just based around `CreateDelegate`. You need private generic static classes, and all sorts of other goodies, but it's damn fast.

Comment: Yah I use the same trick (generic private static class) but usually go the expression route since for example in your solution you could perform an Aggregate AndAlso and then cache that. You'd then not pay the price of LINQ like you do with the Select and the All

Comment: But still I'd not recommend your code or mine to the OP unless they knew what they were doing, which I think they don't

Comment: You don't know that. You could always micro-optimize into `for` loop